# one socket send/receive in thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a socket server and a socket client. The client has only one socket. I have to send/receive data in the client by using threads.

```
static int sock = -1;
static std::mutex mutex;


void hello(const char* message)
{   
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    send(sock, message, strlen(message), 0);
    char buf[512];
    recv(sock, buf, 512, 0);
    lock.unlock();
    printf("%s\n", "here");
}

void f()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        hello("hello");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM , 0);

    ...

    std::thread th(&f);

    th.join();

    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

send/receive terminate program. What's the reason?

Comment: In what programming language?

Comment: с++. I can't use boost lib, there are some reasons

Comment: Apart from anything else, you are not checking the returned result from system calls.

Comment: And not connecting the socket.

Comment: Which you would have realised if you had checked the result from the system calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe because the socket is not connected.

To use a client TCP socket you have to `connect()` it somewhere before sending or receiving.

And to use a server TCP socket you need *another socket* that will call `bind()`, `listen()` and `accept()`.

And obviously, if you want to send the `"hello"` string and get it back, you will need a pair of connected sockets.

You may be interested in the function `socketpair()`, if availiable on your platform, that creates a pair of already connected sockets.

Comment: of course i checked connection (... mean that i check handle and bla bla bla:)) everything is work when i call it in main thread, but when i use another thread, send/recv call std::terminate

Comment: I'm sorry. Server was written by another guy, i found problem. Thanks:) I am crab and the guy how write server too)